# asp.net webforms отображение диалогового окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Есть такой код asp.net webforms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <div id="popup" style="display:none" title="Bla">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('#popup').dialog({
                Width: 600
            });            
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему при нажатии на кнопку окно появляется и сразу исчезает ? Как его можно сделать, чтобы оно не исчезало ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил у себя ваш код - все ок, окно не закрывается
Если уж у вас оно закрывается может стоит напрямую указать `display:block` для `#popup` при нажатии на кнопку?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('#popup').css('display', 'block')
            $('#popup').dialog({
                Width: 600
            });            
        });
</script>
```

**P.S.** использовал библиотеки с google, может в них дело?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```